# c# Add custom method to Lists

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods

I would like to add a method to extend my List behavior, but I'm having trouble. I would like have the 'extension' method in the class where I'm working on it. How can I do it?

I want to do:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>()
        myList.Add("First Value");
        myList.AddMoreValues(); //or myList += AddMoreValues()  ??
    }        

    private void AddMoreValues(this List<string> theList)
    {
        theList.Add("1");
        theList.Add("2");
        ...
    }
}
```

The code above gives me the error:

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: extension methods always have `static` keyword and also inside `static` class and use `this` in the parameter like `(this List<string> theList)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extension methods must be static to use them how you want to use them. Simply add the `static` keyword to your method:

```
private static void AddMoreValues(this List<string> theList)
```

But you're better off putting it in a separate `static` class and making it `public` (it's easier to organise your extension methods that way), something like:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void AddMoreValues(this List<string> theList)
    {
        theList.Add("1");
        theList.Add("2");
        ...
    }
}
```

Extension methods need to be in a `static` class as per section 10.6.9 of the C# spec:

> When the first parameter of a method includes the this modifier, that method is said to be an extension method. Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes. The first parameter of an extension method can have no modifiers other than this, and the parameter type cannot be a pointer type.

Comment: it must be inside `Static` class. Is that true.

Comment: @Rahul That's right, as per the spec: *When the first parameter of a method includes the this modifier, that method is said to be an extension method. Extension methods can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes. The first parameter of an extension method can have no modifiers other than this, and the parameter type cannot be a pointer type.*

Comment: Also If you create extension methods that have the same signature methods as the type you are extending, then the extension methods will never be called.

Comment: @Rahul If the methods share the same signature, you'll no doubt get an Ambigious method call build error.

Comment: Yes agreed that why i mentioned that point so that `@user1208908` user learn something new in case of extension methods..

Comment: do you have knowledge about stored procedure. if yes then may you check my one question..

Comment: Ideally only Lists in MyClass should be able to call the method. But I get the point.  Maybe a derived class?

Comment: @user1208908 Ah right okay, a derived class should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You should define extension methods in a separate, *static* class.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>()
        myList.Add("First Value");
        myList.AddMoreValues();
    }        
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
    public static void AddMoreValues(this List<string> theList)
    {
        theList.Add("1");
        theList.Add("2");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `AddMoreValues` should not be private

Comment: Tx - I don't want all Lists to be able to do this - only Lists in MyClass. But I get the point.